# Oracle 11g Agent Connection to Instance Status Failed

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, centos7, oracle-enterprise-manager, oracle-enterprise-linux

I was installing the Oracle 11g Standard Edition by using below URL :

http://dbaora.com/install-oracle-11g-release-2-11-2-on-centos-linux-7/

After installation is completed all is good I can able to access my DB Console by using my username/password with http://tsm.aitc.local:1158/em URL.

But when I reboot my Server(CentOS 7) and run below command

```
lsnrctl start LISTENER
emctl start dbconsole
```

Then try to hit below URL

http://tsm.aitc.local:1158/em

Then I am getting below error message on DB Console.

[image]

I am using CentOS 7 and Oracle 11g.

Comment: Did you try to start database instance using SQL*PLUS? Try to access the EM after starting database instance.

Comment: @JSapkota Can you please guide me for the command to start database instance by using SQL*PLUS?

Comment: General way is `[oracle@host ]$ sqlplus / as sysdba` then `SQL>startup`, I assume that you have set `ORACLE_SID` and `ORACLE_HOME` environment variables.

Comment: @JSapkota I try `[oracle@tsm ~]$ sqlplus  / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Tue Apr 18 20:33:33 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1586708480 bytes
Fixed Size                  2213736 bytes
Variable Size             973080728 bytes
Database Buffers          603979776 bytes
Redo Buffers                7434240 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL> exit` Then `emctl start dbconsole` but same issue.

Comment: What's the output of `[oracle@host ]$ lsnrctl status listener`? Is your listener providing service for the ORA11G SID?

Comment: @JSapkota I reboot my server then Login as user "oracle" then run `sqlplus  / as sysdba` then `SQL> startup` after that my database instance started. Exit from sqlplus then run `lsnrctl start LISTENER` then run `emctl start dbconsole` and My DB Console run successfully without any error. All is good. But after 15 to 20 Minutes I am not able to access my DB Console again?

Comment: @JSapkota After 15 to 20 Minutes I am not able to access Oracle Enterprise Manager then I just run `ps -ef | grep agent` and kill `emagent` pid. After that run `lsnrctl start LISTENER` then `emctl start dbconsole` and then again everything is ok. Again I am able to access Enterprise Manager perfectly. But I don't know why this behaving like this?

Answer (score 0):

Check configuration of $ORACLE_HOME/$INSTANCE/sysman/config/emoms.properties

Review things started with oracle.sysman.eml.mntr.*